# ADF Calendar performance leak

Tags: calendar, oracle-adf, jdeveloper

I am using JDeveloper 11.1.2.3.0
I have implemented af:calenar functionality in my application. My calendar is based in a ViewObject that queries a database table with a big number of records (500-1000). Performing the selection through a select query to my database table is very fast, only some ms. The problem is that the time to load of my af:calendar is too long. It requires more than 5 seconds. If I just want to change the month, or the calendar view I have to wait approximately that amount of time. I searched a lot through the net but I found no explanation to this. Can anyone please explain why it takes so long? Has anyone ever faced this issue?

PS: I have tested even with JDeveloper 12 and the problem is identically the same

Comment: Have you checked with firebug (for example) what response time of server call? How many this call, weight of the response? Just to narrow down is it server side issue, or client rendering issue.

Comment: Thank you for commenting, it is server side issue, not client. Have you ever faced this issue? What has been your approach toward this?

Comment: Not this issue exactly, just common knowledge. Now make sure that lag is when your browser waiting for the answer from server (means, no data being sent, just waiting for the answer). If thats the case, then underlying procedure that sends response makes it slow. And there is a point where you can start profiling. Check model execution timing and so on (pay attention, that query that BC makes to DB may work differently that one, you make with another SQL tools.

Comment: And one more thing, I hope there is no CLOB/BLOB fields in this query?

Comment: Yes the browser just waits for the response, I have controlled in real time the server logs. At the other side there is no field CLOB/BLOB in the ViewObject. If I use query based view object, the performance increases just a little but still it takes too long. Any idea?

Comment: Enable trace level of logging for jbo and check what query it executing, may be u'll find culprit there.

Comment: Thanks again Nagh, I know where the problem is but I am not able to fix it. This problem relates to the component rendering by the server. I have asked even in OTN about this and nobody gave me an answer, maybe this component is just meant for small purposes and not for real scenarios. Thanks again for your time.

Comment: Hey, we didn't even started yet :p Enable oracle.jbo trace level logging. You'll see in the server logs queries, that are being executed. Catch it and get the execution plan in sqldeveloper. Perhaps it needs some tuning. Beside queries itself, also it may be necessary to look at the jbo itself. But lets go slowly. First thing is queries.

Comment: Nagh thank you very much for your answers and patience. I have enabled logging and I saw that the same query gets executed 4-5 times when page loads :-| However the execution of the query is fast enough and at the other side query gets executed 4-5 times also in other pages but those pages are displayed fast enough. Other pages contains random tables, forms etc. Only in the calendar page happens this problem.

Answer (score 1):

You should look into the viewobject tuning properties to see how many records you fetch in a single network access, and do the same check for the executable that populates your calendar.

Also try using the HTTP Analyzer to see what network traffic is going on and the ADF Logger to check what SQL is being sent to the DB.

https://blogs.oracle.com/shay/entry/monitoring_adf_pages_round_trips

Comment: Thank you for responding Shay, I will try it but the problem is not coming from the VO but from the calendar component rendering. If there are many events withing a month, opening that month's view takes too long, weather for other months having less events will less time (notable time). Have you ever tried to use this component with a big number of events?